# Datacenters in Angola / Africa

Tags: performance, dedicated-server, datacenter

I'm not sure if this is SF-appropriate but I've a client that wants to open his websites to the African market (specially [Angola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angola)), the problem is that the websites that are served by our American / European servers are terribly slow when accessed from African locations, even with a 3.6Mbps Internet connection.

I'm guessing the low speed is due to the geographic distance but I'm not entirely sure.

I've been searching for a while (on Google and on Yellow Pages) for African data centers but I can't find anything that will let us host / rent a dedicated server, and **I'm wondering if anyone has the same problem and most importantly, how did you solved it?**

Some (fast) Websites that I know of:

- [sapo.ao](http://www.sapo.ao/)
- [sapo.cv](http://www.sapo.cv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the websites of 3 datacenters in South Africa:

http://www.is.co.za/

http://www.teraco.co.za/

http://www.rsaweb.co.za/

The last one seems to advertise what you're looking for.

To clear up your sapo example: they are actually hosting that domain from Portugal.

Comment: @gekkz: Thanks, regarding the sapo example: we also have server in Portugal but our webpages take almost one minute to load in Africa while sapo is pretty damn fast. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: This is most likely related to the connectivity you have versus the connectivity sapo uses. It's all about peerings, and in places with poor connectivity it can make a 50milisec or more difference to be connected to the right peer. Do some trace routes from various locations and see what ISPs data gets routed through.